# What does getc method do?

Tags: ruby

What does `getc` method do in ruby? I found this code:

```
class XOREncrypt
  def initialize(inputfile, password, outputfile)
    input = File.open(inputfile,"r")
    pass_array = password.split(//)
    output = File.new(outputfile,"w")
    i = 0
    while c = input.getc
      pass_char = pass_array[i]
      xor = c.chr[0] ^ pass_char[0]
      output.print(xor.chr)
      i+=1
      if i == (pass_array.size - 1)
        i = 0
      end
    end
    input.close
    output.close
  end
 end

puts "Filename for Input : "
inputfile = gets
puts "Insert Password : "
password = gets
puts "Filename for Output : "
outputfile = gets
XOREncrypt.new(inputfile.chomp, password.chomp, outputfile.chomp)
```

What does `getc` method do in ruby? I googled it, but without result.

Comment: Don't Google it, look directly at the documentation. [IO.getc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-getc), or try `ri getc` at the command-line. And, honestly, if you have difficulty with finding the documentation, then perhaps you should back away from Rails, because it's going to blow your mind until you know Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reads the next 8 bit from the file.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/IO.html#method-i-getc

Comment: 8 calls to getc would read the next 8 bytes. Ruby is also at v2.1.0 now.